# Can we delay response of a PHP page until another flag request of same visitor?

Tags: php, sleep

I'm trying to make a chat script, but I don't want the visitor's browser to ask for a new message every 0.5 seconds. Instead, I want the server to send the new message immediately.

I thought I could send a request to the server, and if there aren't any new messages, the server will wait until there is one. This waiting time doesn't need to be long, perhaps 2-3 seconds.

I tried PHP's `sleep()` function:

```
while(1)
{

   $temp=$db->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (id=36 OR id=12) AND clock>".$last_time);

   if ($temp->rowCount()!=0) break;

   sleep(1);

}
```

This "wait until an interrupt" process works when other visitors break the loop, but when the visitor who starts the loop tries to send a message, he waits forever.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

**EDIT**
*System is IIS 7 - PHP Version 5.3.6

Comment: apache only allows 1 connection at a time from the same machine, try increasing the limit, or use nginx or lighttpd or some other appropriate long-polling server.

Comment: Whether this mechanism is advisable is another matter, _but_: you probably need to close the session with `session_write_close();`, otherwise it blocks all other requests. Apache out of the box, contrary to previous comments, usually supports multiple connections from the same ip unless explicitly configured otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wrikken I put session_write_close() before the loop and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you tagged `facebook-chat` here.

Anyways, that method is inappropriate and will over-load your server with database queries. You should use [long-polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) or [websockets](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket%20chat&aq=f&oq=websocket%20chat&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3.2021&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=websocket%20chat%20php&oq=websocket%20chat%20php&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l2j0i22i10i30.2994.3347.0.3509.4.4.0.0.0.0.154.413.0j3.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.LS7TMS3XVhE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ&fp=a2ec104b022b507a&biw=932&bih=606). It might sound like a lot to make the user poll for updates, but when done appropriately its fine.

Comment: I tagged facebook-chat because facebook uses something like that. It makes request wait for 40 seconds if there is no new stuff.

Comment: in fb chat you can't use long polling as far as i'm aware. it just works with a real socket connection - for example with clients like pidgin. it should work with web sockets though.